# How to generate a fake load on linux server for testing oracle R12 application

Tags: linux

I want to know how to generate a fake load on linux server for testing purpose.

We have to get a new server. Before finalizing it we have to test it by generating a fake load so that it can fulfill our future needs.

Is there any software or utility for this purpose.

Thank You

regards

Answer (score 1):

would help if you told what exactly you want to load-test. is it a web app? ot the oracle itself?

one of the best commercial products is [Silkperformer](http://www.borland.com/us/products/silk/silkperformer/index.html)

also take a look at [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/), it's free and let's you test the following:

- Web - HTTP, HTTPS
- SOAP Database via JDBC
- LDAP
- JMS
- Mail - POP3(S) and IMAP(S)

Comment: Thank You for your prompt reply.

I want to test the load on oracle application and on database both.

Comment: cool, try JMeter then, it's quite nice and free as well :) allows you to write some tests using jdbc (so you can test any DB in fact, not only oracle) and also acts as a simplistic webbrowser, so you can test your application as well.